# Does high speed airflow remove water from the plane's windshield more effectively?

Tags: weather, visibility

I have read something from the web that mentions higher speed reduces visibility during rain because water spreads over a larger area and the plane impacts droplets more frequently.

I think that statement isn't true because from my point of view the *high* speed airflow removes water from the plane's windshield more effectively but I am not sure.

Comment: Don't believe everything you read on the web, this place is a good example!  I agree with you though...  (got a link to where you read this?)

Comment: In all but heavy rain, my car's steeply raked windshield lets me turn off the windshield wipers above 60 mph.

Answer (score 4):

What generally happens is the faster you are going, the rain hitting the windshield disperses into smaller and smaller droplet beads running up the glass and actually becomes less noticeable. There is still a refraction error caused by the presence of droplets, which makes horizontal features like terrain or the horizon look lower than they really are, and you have to be aware of that.

As you slow down, the droplet beads running up the windshield get a bit larger and start to impede vision, especially at night if the rain is moderate to heavy. Under 150 kt, typically on approach, moderate to heavy rain can start to affect the view of the runway ahead and you'll need to turn the wipers on (although I found the wipers to be a bit distracting and didn't turn them on unless I really had to).

Operators will sometimes apply RAIN-X to windshields, especially if the outer lamination is acrylic instead of glass, to minimize the need to use the wipers, which can wear on the softer surface of an acrylic windshield.  RAIN-X is a type of wax like treatment that makes water bead into very fine beads, even at very low speeds.
It can just about eliminate the need to use wipers unless rain is extremely heavy.

Comment: I love my RAIN-X!  Are we allowed to promote products here?

Comment: Prolly not lol.  My beef with it, when used on a car, is the wiper leaves behind micro beads created by the coating, and it looks like a smear. So if it's applied, you have avoid the wipers except in extreme cases.